# When I clone a git repository, why does it not show up in GitHub for Mac?

Tags: macos, git, github

I am trying to understand Git and GitHub for Mac.

Example: I try to clone the FacebookSDK git repo like this. In Terminal I write:

```
git clone git://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git [path to where you want to save sdk]
```

git successfully downloads and clones it and I find a folder called facebook-ios-sdk in the specified path.

However GitHub for Mac does not list this repository at all. What I don't understand about GitHub for mac anyway is how is it supposed to know about existing git repositories?

Where am I supposed to install/clone repositories to, so GitHub for Mac recognizes them?

Comment: Well drag and drop will do, the terminal will not create any link with the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell GitHub for Mac about the repo you cloned in Terminal. But it's easiest to use the "Clone in Desktop" button to launch GitHub for Mac and start the clone. See [working-with-repositories](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-repositories) for more info.

That way, GitHub for Mac will automatically know about your new repo.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "+" drop-down button in the bottom left of the GitHub for Mac's main window.

"**Add Local Repository...**" will tell the software about the existing repository you cloned down. "**Create New Repository...**" will clone new projects for you and ensure that they are tracked from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I think GitHub for Mac only allows you to clone repositories that you yourself created or forked. This is because the entire GitHub workflow is centered on forking, developing, and then requesting the upstream repo to pull your changes.

Here is how to do it:

1. Browse to the repo you want to work on and click on <kbd>⑂ Fork</kbd>
2. Open GitHub for Mac
3. File / Reload Repositories, or <kbd>⌘R</kbd>
4. File / Clone Repository, or click on the <kbd>✚ ▾</kbd> button and then on the Clone tab
5. You should be able to see your newly forked repo, select it and <kbd>Clone Repository</kbd>

There's also a  <kbd>Clone in Desktop</kbd> button on the GitHub website (right side) but I could never get it to work. It just sends me to the download page for GitHub for Mac.

Comment: I think your post is helpful to me.